# Can I add an object as a favorite on the lightning favorites list?

Tags: lightning

I mostly use Acocunt/Lead/Opportunity in my setup. 
Is it possible to add these objects as Favorites to the Favorite list?

- I know we can add them as a Browser favorite. But it's better as a shortcut menu since once you go to a sandbox, you can still access the same objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to favourite the "Setup" page of those objects.

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_userdisplay_favorites_considerations.htm):

> You can’t favorite things in setup pages, but you can still access your favorites from these areas.

Comment: yes, that's a known.  thanks, ill wait for next/next/next/next////// release